# Парсинг параметров командной строки

Tags: cocoa, macos, objective-c, синтаксический-анализ

Посоветуйте библиотеку для парсинга параметров командной строки для Objective-C (для OS X приложения)?

**Обновление**

Вот, например, либа такая есть: https://github.com/NSError/ArgumentParser Мне интересно, кто чем пользовался и что порекомендует из своего опыта.

Comment: О_о в смысле? Парсинг массива аргументов?

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: Как бы стандартом в C-подобных языках является `getopt()` (и во всяких вариациях типа `getopt_long()`), для Objective-C тоже они имеются.

Comment: @ivanzoid фигасе, спасибо. подпишусь на вопрос.

Comment: @klopp ну современный Objective-C уже трудно назвать C-подобным языком) И в случае с `getopt()`, как я понимаю, придётся работать с сишными строками, массивами, структурами, чего бы не хотелось (хотелось бы obj-cишных строк, массивов и классов).

Comment: От "классического" `getopt()` там только общая архитектура, если правильно помню + структура ключей и их аргументов. Сейчас не нахожу имплементации что-то, но вот похожее: https://github.com/tomaz/GBCli

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».